# How to ensure type safety over an Object type given a key and value?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Given this type:

```
type Obj = $ReadOnly<{|
  foo: string,
  bar: number
|}>;
```

With an updater function that applies a partial update:

```
const update = (u: $Shape<Obj>) => (obj: Obj) => ({...obj, ...u});
```

How can I write a function that accepts a key and a value, and applies the two to an `Obj` in a type-safe way? I tried:

```
const setKeyValue = (key: $Keys<Obj>) =>
  (value: $ElementType<Obj, typeof key>) =>
    update({[key]: value});
```

But [Flow complains](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDyARgFZgC8YAJAEp4CGAJoQHYxYA8A3gD6pgwUOHABcYAM4YATgEtWAcwA0AsMQbTxrAK4BbYnmmpeAXwB8AbnQBjOKylhtOJgwwEqACm3jqAZQAWDPicJKRmAJSUZmAecGTioZEU0R7cAHQZcaRKYBlp2ibhVqi29hiSeBgA0nhYAGoMMNruMQDWtT41WBIhZBFRqh4Abo3NPgCiMHi6eKwYACq4eL3ZYNj4cFBg7Vj9yY7OrnipANo7ALriI014hVaCQA) that a `string` cannot be written to `bar`, nor a `number` to `foo`. IOW, the `$ElementType<>` definition doesn't seem to be correctly finding the type corresponding to the passed `key`.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `$ElementType<Obj, typeof key>` is `number & string`.  This is because `Keys<Obj>` returns a union of all possible key values and ElementType of that returns the intersection of all possible values.

```
type Obj = $ReadOnly<{|  foo: string, bar: number |}>;

{
  let k: 'foo' = 'foo';
  // Works because Flow knows `k` is exactly `foo` and its value can only be a string.
  let v: $ElementType<Obj, typeof k> = 'wow';
};

{
  let k: $Keys<Obj> = 'foo';
  // ERROR: Flow can't know `typeof k` is exactly `foo` and not also `bar`.
  let v: $ElementType<Obj, typeof k> = 'wow';
};
```

[try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AeQEYBWoAvKACQBKWAhgCa4B20aAPAN4A+ookssALlABnFACcAlowDmAGlD4aYoYwCuAW3xYxoTgF8AfAG5k7RD2hYUoANZCA5H1j3SoR-3smeIUAHVYYjbCClgAxjSqwjgAYnDwtowIwQAGNsmgEsFYAB40oSgsoMlO6TSMdBkowQBuNNCqOOGMoLDMaCGgNCLiUtIAdOagltbVQuQAopbqWIwoACqYWKwEhPLo2LCQtgau9vAInoh6JohmFla2YwDSWGjCy0Q7ZO7OXqA+45SUuJRCsQigJr2aw2RLxZLrLCbWzpTKgHJ5ArtYr8UrlUCJax1YSwIqKMTJAbnEZjSZYaazBbYB6rUCQ6E2J5ufbwQ7HRBAA)

`number & string` isn't very useful:

```
//  Cannot assign `'wow'` to `a` because string [1] is incompatible with number [2].
let a: number & string = 'wow';
// Cannot assign `10` to `b` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2].
let b: number & string = 10;
```

[[try flow]](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiSlAYQIYDtuwC6iYDOxAlgObagAGA5PAnTaPrLZiwEYCmAxpgCuxHqGL4ATmWwVQAbQCMAXVBliq7H1gBbAA6Z8ZLtFHwy+ABahsg7bwnyATEoB0iE4UwAua7fugAMjFJaVkAXlAGJgBuFDAsXAIiUkpqGgUABhY2Wi5ufiERXzseB0UVNQ0tPQMjE1AzS2CpGSdXdx5CLh8bEocg8Rbw0EzYoA)

One potential way to get the desired behavior is with generics. That said, it looks like [ElementType doesn't yet work as expected with Generics](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7820)

Until the above gets worked out, I think this is a reasonable case to use an `any`. It's relatively isolated and does not leak outside of your function.

```
{
  const setKeyValue = (key: $Keys<Obj>) =>
    (value: $ElementType<Obj, typeof key>) =>
      update(({[key]: value}: any));
};
```

Like mentioned in the ticket, there are ways to do this in a typesafe that Flow will understand but they're more verbose.

```
{
  const setKeyValue = (key: $Keys<Obj>) => {
    return {
      foo: (value) => update(({[key]: value})),
      bar: (value) => update(({[key]: value})),
    }[key]; // using an object here is helpful in case you forget a field or if one is added later, Flow will error.
  };
};
```

When Flow isn't sure about something, it typically errors. TypeScript will usually be silent if it's not sure.

ie., the following wont error in TypeScript but should.

```
interface Obj { foo: string; bar: number; }

const update = (u: Partial<Obj>) => (obj: Obj): Obj => ({...obj, ...u});
const setKeyValue = <TKey extends keyof Obj>(key: TKey) => 
    (value: Obj[TKey]) => update({[key]: {'crazy': 'crazy stuff that should error'}})


const w: Obj = {foo: 'hello', bar: 5};
setKeyValue('foo')('world')(w);
```

[[TypeScript Playground]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeyYD2BAXMgM5hSgDmA3MunFKSAK4C2609AvgFB8EBEBWSsADgBM4kZAF5kAClakACkzDA4AGwA8GTAD4AlPMNKCWUgePWsZpTgB0Ly5gA0yF09Y9jtQWFRMggwAGkIAE8ANR1WFAVdABUIyOQIAA9IEEkyZABrKIIYNCxDRULI0hSo0zlzPmQmpQA3OIg7TABtGsiAXTrzCWlIRRwuyr7SHAByBCg4AC9ImdI5heXyMFYYErAACxlyfYJWbUl0qCgCKBmePwFAkTBkAHdO+VxCEmQZ-YhtNoCDNPIxmMgAKw8AIhcJRWLaeKKGbfGbGZGvG7nNGKV7+PhAA)

Comment: Hm, I would have thought my `setKeyValue` calls would be statically analyzable. Why can't Flow refine type of `key` in `setKeyValue('foo')` from `$Keys<Obj>` to `string`?